# Passing Variable of arbitrary Name to Template in Mojolicious

Tags: mojolicious, perl

I wanted to display the count of three database tables: `Data`, `Meta` and `Type`.

So naturally I stash those values, and render them (using `Mojolicious::Lite`).

```
$c->stash(data => $count_data,
          meta => $count_meta,
          type => $count_type,
 );

 $c->render(template => 'tblcount');
```

Turns out, that `data` is a reserved keyword in the stash.
The observed effect was, that after rendering only the value in `$count_data` will be shown... ignoring the template completely. Also no errors.

This was kind of hard to debug (it costed like an hour or so of my sanity).
Also I'm sure I'm not the first one, who is accidentally misusing the data  keyword (or any of the other keywords).

**My question:** Is there any safe way of passing variables with arbitrary names to the template? Or do I just have to life with this possible clash of names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stash takes arbitrary structures, so you can store a hash of arbitrary data.

```
$c->stash(stuff => {data => $count_data, ...});
```

Then using `$stuff->{data}` in the template.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will work, but is kind of a workaround which doesn't 'really' address the actual problem. I better don't do `$c->stash(data => {stuff => $count_stuff, ...});` :-)

Comment: There is no way to put arbitrary keys safely in the stash.

Comment: And the stash is 'the way' to put variables in the template, right? I was hoping for something like `$c->vars` or so, which would be safe.

Comment: The args of the `render` command just put those values in the stash, and it then renders using what is in the stash. There is no direct access otherwise in a Mojolicious app.

Comment: You could actually use `$c->renderer->render` directly to bypass putting its args into the stash, but this is not really supported (you would have to reimplement most of `$c->render` and it involves the currently experimental `respond` method).